# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Failed to read parameter "xxx" from the request body as JSON

Tags: c#, reactjs, json, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I have a React TypeScript application which makes a call to a C# ASP.NET Core 7 Minimal API.

The call from the React app looks like this:

`const resp = await Client.post('https://localhost:7196/institutions', JSON.stringify(doc));`

`Client` is defined as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { jsonrepair } from 'jsonrepair';

export class Client {
    static async post(url: string, jsonData: string) {
        const headers = {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        };
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(url, jsonrepair(jsonData), headers );
            return response?.data;
        } catch (e) {
            return e.message;
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant C# code in my minimal API is as follows:

```
app.MapPost("/institutions", async ([FromBody]string instJson, InstitutionDb instDb, [FromHeader(Name = "Content-Type")] string contentType) =>
{
    var inst = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Institution>(instJson);
    if (inst != null)
    {
        instDb.Institutions.Add(inst);
        await instDb.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.Created($"/institutions/{inst.Id}", inst);
    }
    return null;
});
```

However, when executing it - ***even after verifying that the JSON being passed is legitimate*** (after being cleaned with the TypeScript `jsonrepair` utility), I receive the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Failed to read
> parameter "string instJson" from the request body as JSON.  --->
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted
> to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'StartObject' as a string.    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ExpectedString(JsonTokenType
> tokenType)    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    --- End of
> inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state,
> Utf8JsonReader& reader, Exception ex)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, ReadStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ContinueDeserialize[TValue](ReadBufferState&
> bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack,
> JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromStreamAsync[TValue](Stream
> utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequestJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(HttpRequest
> request, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequestJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(HttpRequest
> request, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.g__TryReadBodyAsync|90_0(HttpContext
> httpContext, Type bodyType, String parameterTypeName, String
> parameterName, Boolean allowEmptyRequestBody, Boolean
> throwOnBadRequest)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.Log.InvalidJsonRequestBody(HttpContext
> httpContext, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Exception
> exception, Boolean shouldThrow)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.g__TryReadBodyAsync|90_0(HttpContext
> httpContext, Type bodyType, String parameterTypeName, String
> parameterName, Boolean allowEmptyRequestBody, Boolean
> throwOnBadRequest)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass90_2.<b__2>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

The interesting thing is that if I debug and set a breakpoint on (or inside) `app.MapPost()`, **the breakpoint does not get hit**.

Why is this happening?  Why is the endpoint failing, even with valid JSON and the content-type header being set correctly?  Why am I unable to set a breakpoint in my C# code?

Any suggestions?  I have searched this error extensively on StackOverflow and elsewhere.  Others have reported this error but none of the solutions I've tried have worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you sending your data as a json, not as a string, so changed the header

```
app.MapPost("/institutions", async ([FromBody]Institution inst)
```

and remove deserialization code